# R window desktop for Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos, add-in

I'm wondering if there is a sort of desktop add-on for R on Mac OS X that I can install?  I'm looking for something similar to what I have for Matlab (as opposed to the sea of floating windows I currently have for R).  It would make organization so much more simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for an IDE (integrated developer's environment)? [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) is awesome.